# Arrays of arrays along a path

Tags: modifiers, instances

I am attempting to create a ring of several levels of benches through arrays only. Either this is a little too advanced for Blender or I am missing a step.

I create a cylinder as the back support. I create a cube and stretch it to be the "ramp" that the benches are attached to, and add an Array to make two of them. I create another cube to be one bench, then add an Array to make enough of them to fill the "ramp".

[image]

According to one tip of duplicating a group of objects I create a plane and parent these pieces to the plane, then add an Array and Curve to get the plane and its children to follow the curve I have set up. However, all the instances seem to sheer rather than rotate along the path.

[image]

How would I go about so that the set faces inward? Will I have to join all my instances together into one mesh? I heard that instances would speed things up but am I over-using it?

[image]

Comment: nothing is too advanced for Blender!! Your explanation is a bit hard to follow though, maybe show a picture of what you would like to achieve, it will help to find the best way

Comment: @moonboots I added an extra picture depicting the benches. I want that entire set to follow the curve path so it becomes a circle of benches, like in a circus.

Comment: Did you make sure the origins of the curve, the plane and the benches objects are on the same spot ?

Comment: @Gorgious What would constitute as "same spot"? That they are all at absolute 0? Just tried moving the pieces around and they still sheered.

Comment: It's not clear what's your problem, also you may have change the scale of your curve in Object mode, in that case apply the scale and in Edit mode select all the vertices and in the N panel > Transform > change the Mean Radius to 1

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots All Scales and Radiuses are 1. And aside from that picture of cubes skewing in a direction I do not want, how else am I to explain the problem? Or rather how detailed should I be about describing what a set of benches/bleachers should look like at a football field?

Comment: try to put the curve origin to its center for example, then put your object at the exact same point. Or maybe share your file

Comment: @moonboots I tried Gorgious suggestion to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't apply the scale of your plank objects, so when they twist they deform badly, just apply the scale with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. By the way your setting seems a bit complicated, why not just make one unique object and maybe, if the deformation is not noticeable, duplicate it around with *Array + Curve*?

[image]

Comment: So I was over-using the instancing? Go figure.

Comment: @Edward The benefit of instancing is that the mesh doesn't get curved with the curve modifier. In this case you won't notice it much, but it is very noticeable if your curve has sharp corners

Comment: yes Gorgious is right, it won't be very noticeable here, do as you want, try to be as simple as possible, for example don't hesitate to join the objects, etc...